# Python PyQt not updating until if statement is done

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

My pyqt doesn't seem to update until an if statement finishes.  I've tried to comment out various sections of it to isolate the problem, but it still remains that all of the changes I make in the if statement happen all at once after the if statement finishes.

This is within a class that inherits from a pyqt gui class.

The code in question: (I've commented out some things to simplify in order to eliminate the possibility of them interfering.)

```
        if self.state == 3:
            try:
                HM=float(self.ui.BV.text())
                b=True
            except:
                self.mess("Please give me a number. (: ")
                b=False
            if b:
                print "we got our number",HM
                print "first",HM <= float(self.ullim)
                print "second",HM >= float(self.llim)
                if HM <= float(self.ullim) and HM >= float(self.llim):
                    print "conditions satisfied"
                    #self.changestate(4)
                    print "this should be four:",self.state
                    self.mess("Sending transaction...")
                    print "issues1",self.ui.Message.text()
                    self.txid="Test id"#bitcoinc2.sendt(self.curad, HM)
                    self.mess("Transaction complete.  ID: %s" % self.txid)
                    print "issues2",self.ui.Message.text()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    #self.changestate(0)
                    return

            self.mess("Invalid number...")
            return
```

I have defined a function mess which takes self and a string and sets a Qlabel to the string.

When ran, I get something a bit like this:

```
we got our number 0.1
first True
second True
conditions satisfied
this should be four: 3
Setting message to Sending transaction...
issues1 Sending transaction...
Setting message to Transaction complete.  ID: Test id
issues2 Transaction complete.  ID: Test id
Setting message to Press any button to scan the qr code.
```

Every other time I try to change the text through self.mess(message), it works.  But not this one, and I can't seem to figure out what's different.

EDIT: I don't think it is a duplicate of the linked one, as even the statements before the sleep are hung up until after the if finishes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQt GUI order of operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916377/pyqt-gui-order-of-operations)

Comment: In response to your edit: I'm still convinced it is a duplicate. I'll quote the relevant part of the answer there. "The GUI is not updated/drawn until control is returned to the Qt event loop.". Control is not returned until the current method has finished executing. As such, until the current method you are in, finishes, (eg hits the return statement) none of your changes will be shown on the GUI. If you still feel this is not true, you may need to provide more outline of how this bit of code fits in with the larger program (eg, where is it called from, is it in another thread, etc).

Comment: This fixed my problem upon looking deeper into it, thank you.