# pyside widget.show not blocking

Tags: python, pyside

I wrote a little application, that saves small videos it generates. The code pasted should do the following:

1. show  dialog to the user to choose a directory
2. if directory is not empty show widget that has a circle running around so there's a feedback that something is going on
3. then generate the movies (which takes some time and most if it has handled with multiprocessing pool)
4. (not included in snippet, but the code would go on to do more background stuff, so the loading widget would stay on for a while

Code:

```
def saveMovie(self):
    self.pause()

    if not os.path.exists("outputs"):
        os.makedirs("outputs")
    dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,dir="outputs",options=QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)

    if not dir == '':
        self.loading = True
        self.loadingWidget.show()
        name = os.path.basename(dir) + "_"
        settings = sm.fetch_settings()
        swarms,l,l1,l2 = self.generate_movies()
```

Now instead of this, what happens is that the dialog disappears and the loading widget is shown only after the program has existed from `self.generate_movies()`. What am I missing?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917237/1994235

Comment: So this would mean I somehow have to return to main after calling show() and than go on to self.generate_movies().

Comment: You need to return control to the Qt event loop. The event loop is what called your `saveMovie` method in the first place, so as soon as `saveMovie()` ends, Qt can start redrawing the appropriate widgets. Given that `generate_movies()` is using a multiprocessing pool already, you basically want to change your program so that it doesn't wait for a response from `generate_movies()` but polls for the response later (e.g. use a `QTimer` to poll)

Comment: @three_pineapples thanks!