# Timing of messages in PyQT list view window to happen before a function runs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, benchmarking

I have some python PyQT code where a user will click a button and a process kicks off to download some data from a website. While this is happening I want a message to appear in list window to say "please wait" so they know that something is happening.

However the timing is off and the message appears after the processing has finished even though I've added the code for the message status at the start of the class function for the button click to start the process.
This is a brief version of the code I have:

```
self.statusfeed.addItem("Please Wait....Updating database from the web") 
update_db()
self.statusfeed.addItem("Database updated")
```

The function update_db() runs the downloading.

This is the main part of the update function other than a dictonary of weblinks to get the files from:

```
for filename, weblink in web_links:
  netfile = urllib2.urlopen(weblink)
  out_fp = open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'w')
  out_fp.write(netfile.read())
  out_fp.close
```

However the please wait status is not updating until after the downloading is done.  How can I force it to wait and update the status in the order that I've show above?

Comment: I think you will need to provide some more details (code) on the `update_db()` function. It doesn't seem like it is actually running in the background like you said, but maybe that is by design? Does the `update_db()` function launch a thread or process and not return until it is complete? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917237/1994235) answer explains why you see the messages appear at the unexpected times.

Comment: Ok the update_db() function uses urllib2 to open seven files on seven weburls and the files are written to a local directory.

Comment: I'm a complete noob with threads etc so you'll have to go slow with me there...

Comment: Original post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` before the call to `update_db()`. This will give the UI to update itself according to the events that are pending.

Comment: Brilliant I was chatting to my husband about this today and he thought there must be some sort of GUI update process that can be run before the function. I'm very new to pyqt and only scratched the surface of what it can do so thanks!